# graphQL - is it possible to resolve relational data to different types from a single resolver function?

Tags: types, graphql

I will try to keep this example simple.

So I have two tables - one for posts and one for users. The tables will of course be linked via posts.user_id and users.id. In my application, I will be fetching an array of posts with the users details (as you would expect).

```js
export default gql`
  query ArticlePosts($articleId: String!) {
    articlePosts (articleId: $articleId)  {
      id
      comment
      poster {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  }
`
```

typeDef...

```js
export default `

  type ArticlePost {
    id
    comment
    poster: User!
  }

  type User {
    id: Int!
    username: String!
  }

  type Query {
    articlePosts(articleId: String!): [ArticlePost!]
  }
`
```

I have experimented with 2 different ways of resolving: -

1. The resolver returns an array of the ArticlePost type and performs query on the user for each ArticlePost type returned from the parent query (as above)
2. The resolver returns an array of the ArticlePost type (as above) with the poster/user details returned from the sequelize query by way of a simple INNER JOIN statement in the SQL.

Now obviously the 2nd way of resolving performs only a single database query whereas the first option is going to perform many queries to pull back the relational data.

Is there any way to perform the 2nd way of doing it while still making sure the two different types (ArticlePost and User) are still recognised by graphQL? Would it be as simple as having a child of the parent (ArticlePost) resolver return the appropriate fields from the JOIN query: -

```js
ArticlePost: {
  poster: async (parent, args, context) => {
 return {id: parent.posterId, id: parent.posterUsername}
  },
}
```

I am not sure if this is a good practice any if there is a cleaner way to do this, perhaps handling it in the parent resolver call itself? I am quite new to graphQL so I have never come across this sort of scenario before.

Thanks.

Comment: So did you get any solution for this. I myself required the same. Thanks and let me know.

Comment: I just went back to doing it the proper graphQL way. Once the project comes closer to completion, I am going to look over the GQL stuff and work on optimisation. I will let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: I think i might have find the way , we can query our custom query in main queryType resolve, then for eg: we have a relation address on userType, so from address resolve under userType we can access the $root data that it. `'address' =>"type" => new UserAddressType, 'resolve' => function($root, $args, $context) { return $root;}],`